# Working with appcelerator titanium ti.coremotion on ios 8+

Tags: ios8, titanium, appcelerator, core-motion

I am trying to develop a stepcounter using the ti.coremotion module.

I am trying to implement http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Modules.CoreMotion on devices with ios 8 and 9, but as it says in the doc, this only works for ios 7. I am stuck now. I tried running it on a device with ios8 and it said "Device does not supports step counting".

I tried searching it on google and got this: https://github.com/benbahrenburg/Ti.CoreMotion
which says it is for ios 7+ but works with sdk 3.2 only. What I am working with is sdk 4.1 and I need it as 3.2 will not work for other things.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I just build an app with SDK 5.0.2.GA to my iPhone 6S running iOS 9.1 and this sample code and it worked fine:

```
var CoreMotion = require("ti.coremotion");

// This code checks to see if the device can gather step counting data
if (CoreMotion.isStepCountingAvailable()) {
    // If it can, it starts the step counter and outputs the data to the console
    CoreMotion.startStepCountingUpdates({stepCounts: 1}, function(e){
        Ti.API.error(JSON.stringify(e.numberOfSteps));
    });
} else {
    Ti.API.error('This device does not support counting steps.');
}
```

What device are you testing on? Does it work for you on a device running iOS 9?

If you have reproducible code/steps/environment then please create a JIRA ticket: http://jira.appcelerator.org

Comment: Thanks Fokke. Appreciate your reply.

I am using iphone 5. I figured out later that core motion is only supported in iphone 5s and devices later. So, I guess it will work when I'll try it in those devices.

So, now I am implementing my code as a calorie calculator for devices before 5s and step counter+calorie calculator for other devices.

For devices before 5s, I am trying to implement the same with the help of GPS and accelerometer. Just wanted to know if I have implemented the right approach for older devices or is there something else I should be looking on.

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: Calorie calculator as in calculating distance walked/ran with gps with max accuracy and then the formula with height, weight, gender and age.

Comment: No idea if gps+acceleromoter is going to give you the same thing as a pedometer.

Comment: Yeah. I figured it out after I commented it. Gps was not that good in small workouts. But accelerometer was pretty close. I saw this app on appstore and it worked perfectly fine on devices without core motion processor.

https://itunes.apple.com/en/app/footsteps-pedometer-free/id364911801?mt=8

I think they have implemented the same with accelerometer, as it was not tracking any location. Any idea how only accelerometer can be used to detect steps? I wrote a logic based on data analysis and it worked so far, not sure if it'll work everytime. Any leads according to you?